# iOS application integration with pinterest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, pinterest

What is the most **reliable** way currently to allow pinterest sharing from iOS app?

Pinterest API is not public yet and only suggested way to share is their web button.

Comment: @mydogisbox web button is inconvenient for the user since you must show additional webview and render some kind of mobile-optimized page on your website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of May 20th 2013, Pinterest have released an iOS SDK for pinning content.

Check out [their Developers site](http://developers.pinterest.com) for more information.

Comment: anyone has url to sample code? need to find more details on how to do it

Comment: Did you go to the link in my post? If you click "iOS SDK" you should find what you need.

Answer (score 11):

I made a pinterest integration in my iPad app. But, because Pinterest doesn't have an API for posting yet, I used the following method. I just create programmatically an HTML Web Page and add a Pin it button to that page programmatically. Then I show a Web View and allow user to click Pin it once more. These are more explained steps.

1) Create a WebViewController, that has a UIWebView. Add Close button, add UIWebViewDelegateProtocol, spinner, htmlString property.

2) Generate an HTML programmatically to put to that UIWebView, when user clicks your "Pin it" button in your app. In this case I put to the HTML page different images for different products.

```
- (NSString*) generatePinterestHTMLForSKU:(NSString*)sku {
NSString *description = @"Post your description here";

// Generate urls for button and image
NSString *sUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://d30t6wl9ttrlhf.cloudfront.net/media/catalog/product/Heros/%@-1.jpg", sku];
NSLog(@"URL:%@", sUrl);
NSString *protectedUrl = (__bridge NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,(__bridge CFStringRef)sUrl, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding));
NSLog(@"Protected URL:%@", protectedUrl);
NSString *imageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"", sUrl];
NSString *buttonUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=www.flor.com&media=%@&description=%@\"", protectedUrl, description];

NSMutableString *htmlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:1000];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"<html> <body>"];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"<p align=\"center\"><a href=%@ class=\"pin-it-button\" count-layout=\"horizontal\"><img border=\"0\" src=\"http://assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png\" title=\"Pin It\" /></a></p>", buttonUrl];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"<p align=\"center\"><img width=\"400px\" height = \"400px\" src=%@></img></p>", imageUrl];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js\"></script>"];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"</body> </html>"];
return htmlString;
}
```

This is an example of my HTML page generation method.

3) Create a method to call when user taps your "Pin it" button, which shows that webView with the image, that you will post and the "Pin it" button on the UIWebView. This is my example:

```
- (void) postToPinterest {

NSString *htmlString = [self generatePinterestHTMLForSKU:self.flProduct.sku];
NSLog(@"Generated HTML String:%@", htmlString);
WebViewController *webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];
webViewController.htmlString = htmlString;
webViewController.showSpinner = YES;

[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentModalViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
}
```

4) Put a "Close" button to your WebViewController to close it. Also you can add spinners to track the loading of the UIWebView.

```
- (IBAction)closeClicked:(id)sender {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
if (showSpinner) {
    // If we want to show Spinner, we show it everyTime
    [UIHelper startShowingSpinner:self.webView];
}
else {
    // If we don't -> we show it only once (some sites annoy with it)
    if (!spinnerWasShown) {
        [UIHelper startShowingSpinner:self.webView];
        spinnerWasShown = YES; 
    }
}
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [UIHelper stopShowingSpinner];
}
```

P.S. I used the same method to add Google Plus's +1 button to the iPad app. (It doesn't have posting API too, only readonly API at the moment)

Comment: Note to anyone using this code - watch for the percent encoded string, and the wordiness of creating strings using format strings but just passing in a static string.

Answer (score 5):

If you only want to share(i.e. pin on a user board), then you can use iphone-URL-Scheme and call the Pinterest application along with the parameters **url**(URL of the page to pin),  **media**(URL of the image to pin) & **description**(Description of the page to be pinned). Present a UIAlertView and forward them to appstore to download the official Pinterest application if the user has not installed it.

**Reference**:
http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Pinterest

**Code to open Pinterest Applicaiton:**

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"pinit12://pinterest.com/pin/create/bookmarklet/?url=URL-OF-THE-PAGE-TO-PIN&media=URL-OF-THE-IMAGE-TO-PIN&description=ENTER-YOUR-DESCRIPTION-FOR-THE-PIN"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Pinterest" message:@"Would you like to download Pinterest Application to share?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Continue", nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

**UIAlertViewDelegate Method**

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 1){
        NSString *stringURL = @"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pinterest/id429047995?mt=8";
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this code but canOpenUrl always returns NO, although I already installed Pinterest on my device. I think maybe it is because I already have implemented share funcions on facebook, google+, ... Is there something I should add to the AppDelegate method - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation: to get the Pinterest App opened?

Comment: This no longer works in the new api.

Answer (score 2):

I've looked high and low too. I've even contacted Pinterest Team about an SDK. The closest thing I have found is a PHP wrapper on github https://github.com/kellan/pinterest.api.php.

It's not the best solution though because it is unofficial api and will most likely break.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to integrate Pinterest with Custom URL Scheme, also download the Pinterest application on my device, but not abel to integrate with it.

And the thing is that i don't want to used webView for integration so is it possible to do that, i didn't found any application on app store which have pinterest integration.

I did googling also but all worse, Snapguide also remove pinterest integration from their application.

I used a webView code to pin image , no need to open full Pinterest website,

```
NSString *urlStr =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://pinterest.com/pin/create/bookmarklet/?url=www.<domainname>.com&media=http://<domainname>.files.com/hello.jpg?w=495&description=hello"];
```

This would be easy but with webView and that i don't want.