# Any way to upload image to pinterest with iOS SDK, maybe using a fileURL?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, pinterest

Hi I'm trying to find a way to post/upload a locally generated image to pinterest with iOS SDK.

I'm doing the pinterest integration with `UIWebView` given that there is no public API and tried to use for the image url a `fileURLWithPath:` with no success obviously.

Does anyone have any idea if this can be accomplished?

The pinterest app obviously allows you to upload/pin an image from the camera roll.

Is there any way to embed that kind of functionality in my app?

Thank you!

Comment: did u check this already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909511/ios-application-integration-with-pinterest

Comment: Yes I did. That is a good answer but is not covering what I need here (to upload and pin an image from my camera roll).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to post using a multipart/form data type of request. Here is an example of how to do it.
https://forrst.com/posts/Mutlipart_Form_Data_and_image_sending-Vw3

Comment: Ok, and how would I use that in conjunction with the Pinterest scripts/html api?