# Can I share photos on Pinterest?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, pinterest

Can I share my photos on Pinterest using API? I'm developing an application in iOS and want to share my photos from my application to Pinterest.com

Comment: Is that pinterest or printrest.com??

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909511/ios-application-integration-with-pinterest

Comment: @TheSaad I don't see any website in that name

Comment: sorry its http://pinterest.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try offical SDK https://developers.pinterest.com/ios/
You can add it using CocoaPods:

```
-> Pinterest-iOS (2.3)
   The iOS Pinterest SDK.
   pod 'Pinterest-iOS', '~> 2.3'
   - Homepage: http://developers.pinterest.com/ios/
   - Source:   https://pinterest-ota-builds.s3.amazonaws.com/PinItSDKiOS.zip
   - Versions: 2.3 [master repo]
```

Comment: CocoaPods keeps failing to fetch the source (203 forbidden). Alternative source link?